# Localization and Direct limit

Tags: category-theory, commutative-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $ A $ be a ring.

Let $ I $ be a preordered set, filtering.

Let $ \Sigma $ a multiplicative subset of $ A $.

Suppose for any given $ i \in I $ a multiplicative subset $ S_i $ of $ A $ contained in $ \Sigma $.

Make the following assumptions:

- $ \Sigma = \displaystyle \bigcup_i S_i $
- For $ (i, j) \in I^2 $ with $ i \leq j $, elements $ S_i $ become invertible in $ S_ {j}^{-1} A $.

$ \mathcal{D} = ((S_{i}^{-1} A)_{i \in I} \ , \ (S_{i}^{-1} A \to S_{j}^{-1} A)_{i \leq j}) $ is a commutative diagram in the category of filter $ A $ - algebras.

**Question** :

Show that $ \displaystyle \lim_{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{D} \simeq \Sigma^{-1} A $.

To do that, we need to show that :

$ 1) $ exist morphisms $ \pi_i: S_{i}^{-1} A \to \Sigma^{-1} A $ such that $ \pi_{i + p} f_{i, i + p } = \pi_{i} $.

$ 2) $ for any group $ B $ equipped with morphisms $ \pi_i: S_{i}^{-1} A \to B $ such that $ p_{i + p} f_{i, i + p} = p_{i} $ there exists a unique morphism $ g: \Sigma^{-1} A \to B $ such that $ p_i = g \circ \pi_i $.

But, i d'ont know how to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help.